# perl swap two words

Tags: regex, perl

Good Day,

I have a simple working routine in Perl that swaps two words:

i.e.  John Doe ----->  Doe John

Here it is:

```
sub SwapTokens()
{
    my ($currentToken) = @_;

    $currentToken =~ s/([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+)/$2 $1/;
    # $currentToken =~ s/(\u\L) (\u\L)/$2 $1/;
    return $currentToken;
}
```

The following usage yields exactly what I want:

```
print &SwapTokens("John Doe");
```

But when I uncomment out the line '$currentToken =~ s/(\u\L) (\u\L)/$2 $1/;

I get an error.  Am I missing something, it looks like my syntax is correct.

TIA,

coson

Comment: Could _really_ help if you elaborate more than "I get an error"; why are you trying the second regex if the first one already works as required?

Comment: The error I'm receiving is:

syntax error at script.pl line XX, near "(\u\L) (\u\L"
Illegal declaration of subroutine main::IsTitleCase2 at scriptname.pl

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`\L` means ["lowercase till `\E`"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html); i.e., it needs to be followed at some point by `\E`. You do not have `\E` in your regex, thus it is not valid; adding `\E` after each `\L` gets the script to compile, though I have no idea what you are actually trying to accomplish there.

Comment: I'm trying to swap two words with each other.  The regex I'm using should account for title case words.

Comment: Tried that and got:

Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(+ <-- HERE ) (+)/ at scriptname.pl line 31.

Comment: `\u.\L.*\E` is the same as `..*`, and `[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*` is basically an old way of doing the (previously posted) `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+`.

Answer (score 5):

`\u` is not a regex atom that match a uppercase letter. `\L` is not a regex atom that match a number of lowercase letters. You're looking for

```
s/(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+) (\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)/$2 $1/;

\p{Lu}  Uppercase letter.
\p{Ll}  Lowercase letter.

$ unichars '\p{Lu}' | head -n 5
 A  U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
 B  U+0042 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
 C  U+0043 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
 D  U+0044 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
 E  U+0045 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E

$ unichars '\p{Ll}' | head -n 5
 a  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
 b  U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B
 c  U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C
 d  U+0064 LATIN SMALL LETTER D
 e  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E
```

Comment: +1 for using the unicode properties, it could really start an interesting discussion if the OP is interested. )

Comment: @raina77ow, The bigger issue is the belief that names follow such a limited pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
sub swap_the_words {
  my ($processed_string) = @_;
  $processed_string =~ s/([A-Z][A-Za-z]+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)/$2 $1/;
  return $processed_string;
}
print swap_the_words('John Doe'); # prints Doe John
```

As for `\u` and `\l`, they are good for modifying the *string* - not the regex. For example, you can slightly alter your script like that...

```
  $processed_string =~ s/([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)/\u\L$2\E \u\L$1\E/i;
  ...
  print swap_the_words('cOsOn hAcKeR'); # Hacker Coson
```

... so your words are not only swapped, but given the proper case as well. Note, though, that these modifiers are used in the replacement part of `s///` operator.